# Converting a Pandas DataFrame to R dataframe using Rpy2

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

I have a pandas dataframe that I convert to R dataframe using the convert_to_r_dataframe method from pandas.rpy.common. I have it set up as such:

```
self.event = pd.read_csv('C://' + self.event_var.get() + '.csv')
final_products = pd.DataFrame({'Product': self.event.Product, 'Size': self.event.Size, 'Order': self.event.Order})
r.assign('final_products', com.convert_to_r_dataframe(final_products))
r.assign('EventName', self.event_var.get())
r.assign('EventTime', self.eventtime_var.get())
r.source('application.r')
```

where self.event_var.get() retrieves a user input in the GUI (I am creating an application using Tkinter). Product, Size, and Order are columns from the CSV file.

Since Rpy2 sets the R environment within Python, I would expect the final_products R dataframe to be understood by the R environment. Unfortunately, while the R script does run, it does not give the correct results (I create graphs using the R script but they are just empty when the program terminates). However, the EventName and EventTime variables do work. Is there something that I am missing here? Any ideas to why the assignment of the R dataframe within Python is not correctly being interpreted by the R environment?

The error obtained:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "G:\Development\workspace\GUI\GUI.py", line 126, in evaluate
    r.source('application.r')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 35, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you print the type of final_products before the assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is going to be difficult because the Python -> R transformation [is better than it used to be](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/123/conversion-from-rpy2s-r-dataframe-to), but isn't perfect, and [is still hard on Windows currently](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html), which it looks like you're using.

This is a bit of a hack, but as a work-around you might try setting the name and time variables while you are assigning the pd.DataFrame **before** you convert the DataFrame into R.

Once it's in R, you'll need to use R functions to operate on the data frame, rather than your python functions---even your getter and setter will need to be passed into the R environment in a way that looks more like this:

```
myfunct = robjects.r('''
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        f(3)
        ''')
```

from [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/introduction.html).

But just to check that your DataFrame is being converted appropriately in the first place, you might start your debugging by running this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from datetime import datetime

n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [datetime.now() for t in range(n)],
    "value": np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
    })

r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
print(r_dataframe)
```

Is that producing something that looks like an R print statement of a dataframe, like so

```
>>>             timestamp        value
0 2014-06-03 15:02:20 -0.36672....
1 2014-06-03 15:02:20 -0.89136....
2 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.509215....
3 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.862909....
4 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.389879....
5 2014-06-03 15:02:20 -0.80607....
6 2014-06-03 15:02:20 -0.97116....
7 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.376419....
8 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.848243....
9 2014-06-03 15:02:20 0.446798....
```

Example peeled from [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/R-and-pandas-and-what-ive-learned-about-each.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html).

Answer (score 9):

**Great answer** @Mittenchops. Since *convert_to_r_dataframe* is deprecated. Updating the above example with rpy2 interface

```py
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": [datetime.now() for t in range(n)],
    "value": np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
})
r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
print(r_dataframe)
```

Comment: pandas2ri.py2rpy_pandasdataframe(df) worked for me